# Split Quicktime Clip Collection Into Individual Videos

Tags: macos, mac, video, quicktime, video-editing

For whatever reason, my camcorder saves recorded videos as "clips" all bundled into a massive AVCHD movie file. I can open each clip individually and manually export it through Quicktime, but this is a time consuming process I would prefer to automate. What is the best way to automate exporting each of these individual "clips" into their own movie files?

For reference, the "clips" view that shows upon opening the huge AVCHD file looks like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up just opening each file in QuickTime and exporting each clip manually. It wasn't the optimal solution, but did get the job done.

For future viewers, showing package contents on the video file did yield a set of individual movie files in MTS format. I defaulted to manually exporting each clip, however, because I wanted the files in MP4 and didn't have access to a video converter app. However, that would have been a viable option as well.

Comment: Sweet, this will be even easier for me since I just want a single video out of a 30GB worth of video that is however many  individual videos, but I just need one. This will work perfect - lots easier than what I was expecting to have to do..

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Automator to set up an action, such as the one here:

[image]

This uses the "Get Specified Movies" action to take whatever files you desire, and then uses the "Encode Media" action to convert each of them to your desired format before copying them to your selected destination. You could get fancier with it if you like, but this should cover the basics.

Comment: Good idea, but control clicking on a clip won't bring up a contextual menu from which to activate a service.

Comment: Build the workflow in Automator and then hit the "play" button in the top right of the window.

Comment: I tried. The Automator action wants a single movie file, which I don't yet have.

Comment: Sorry, I obviously didn't fully understand what the situation with the files was.

Comment: No problem, I appreciate your input. I actually thought about using Automator at first as well, but hit a similar roadblock in my attempt that you did in yours.